# Laravel 4 eloquent models chaining additional where clauses

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I Have the following code (member is just a standard Eloquent model)

```
$members = new Member;
$members->where('user_id', '=', 5);
$_members = $members->get();
```

The last query run produces "`SELECT * from members`", so it seems to be ignoring my where clause, what am I doing wrong here?

By the way I know I could do `$members = new Member::where(...)` etc... but I will be adding the `where` clauses in a loop in order to create filtering on the results from the database.

**UPDATE**

The only way around this seems to be to add a where that will catch all on initialization such as:

```
 $members = Member::where('member_id', '<>', 0);
 $members->where('user_id', '=', 5);
 $_members = $members->get();
```

But this seems quite a bit of a hack. I am not trying to do anything complicated so I cant be the only one who has had this problem?

**FIXED MAYBE**

For anyone who has stumbled here I have fixed this by using:

```
$members =  Member::query();
$members->where('user_id', '=', 5);
$_members = $members->get();
```

Not sure if that is the correct way but it works for me and doesn't appear like a hack.

Comment: The only difference between a working example and a non-working one is that the first call on `Member` is a static one. Your fix ensures that the first call on `Member` is a static one. So maybe you should have a look at the sources and find out why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe Eloquent works like that.

Try this...

```
$members = new Member;
$members = $members->where('user_id', '=', 5);
$members = $members->get();
```

Comment: I'm sorry I cant see the difference between what you have put and what I had originally?

Comment: There *is* a difference - the output of the call to `->where()` is being re-set as the $members variable. The point is that your code would work if originally $members was an instance of Builder. But as it happens it's an instance of Model (okay Member), so when you call `where` on it it has to first return a Builder. Then you can call further `where`s without having to set a variable.

Comment: And your "fixed maybe" part goes to prove this - you start off with an instance of Builder by calling Model::query(), which you then build on without having to re-set any variables.

Comment: Ah sorry I failed to notice the difference originally for some reason, that makes perfect sense now, Thank you very much for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

There is a much better way to achieve what you need here using [query scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes). Here is what you need to do.

In your Member.php model do the following:

```
public function scopeMembers($query, $condition1, $condition2)
{
    if ( ! empty($condition1))
    {
        $query = $query->where('column1', $condition1);
    }

    if ( ! empty($condition2))
    {
        // Use if ( ! empty($condition2[0]) { $query->whereIn('column2', $condition2); } if you are exploding the input in the controller.
        $query = $query->where('column2', $condition2);
    }
}
```

In your controller do this:

```
protected $member;

public function __construct(Member $member)
{
    $this->member = $member;
}

public function getMembers()
{
    $condition1 = Input::get('condition1');
    $condition2 = Input::get('condition2');

    $members = $this->member->members($condition1, $condition2)->paginate(10);

    return View::make('members', compact('members'));
}
```

This is a very basic example that can be expanded upon depending on what you need. As you can see you can pass as many conditions as you require to the query scope.

Comment: That great, im new to laravel and there seems quite alot to learn, I hadnt come across query scopes before. I'm struggling through it without knowing the best practices so your advice is extremely helpful! Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = Member::where('user_id', 5);

if ( $someCondition )
{
    $query->where(....);
}

$members = $query->get();
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph, but I will need to add more where clauses depending on what the user has selected so cannot call get() until the very end

Comment: That does work however how is it possible without the initial where clause as I don't want the results to be filtered by anything as default?

Comment: That is exactly what I have got in my question minus the if() bit. The additional where does not get executed when trying to do it that way, are you able to replicate or is it just me?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you have to call
    find()
instead of
    get()
?

Comment: With find() dont you have to pass an additional parameter such as the id of the record? this would make the searching irrelevant

Comment: Correct: definitely not find. Get is fine.