# Adding where clause dynamically to a query with pagination in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a list of items that I want to be able to filter using some buttons in the view (show, which are active, show only ones that start with a certain letter, etc) and I was making a different query for each possible combination and that was getting out of hand as soon as I have more than 3 buttons to filter.

So I want to add a where clause to my initial query depending on the buttons pressed, but what I have so far isn't working and I don't know if it's the pagination:

(This is an example with just one button, I'd add more conditions later but this isn't working already).

```
public function index()
{
    $hostesses = Hostess::orderBy('lastname', 'asc')
                ->paginate(30);

    if (Input::has('l')){
        $hostesses->where('lastname', 'like', Input::get('l').'%');
    }

    $this->layout->content = View::make('hostesses.index', compact('hostesses'));
}
```

I get this error on the view:

```
ErrorException

call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Support\Collection' does not have a method 'where'
```

Comment: You probably need to do it before the paginate call.

Comment: Yeah, like Jessica mentioned you probably need to put the if statement before the ->paginate. You may get an error this way also then I would suggest concatenating the variable I believe that would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$hostesses = Hostess::orderBy('lastname', 'asc');

if (Input::has('l')){
    $hostesses->where('lastname', 'like', Input::get('l').'%');
}

$results = $hostessess->paginate(30);
```

Something like that?

Comment: Yeah, that was it, I thought I add the logic of it wrong but it was just the pagination. I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: This won't work.  You must change `$hostesses->where('lastname', 'like', Input::get('l').'%');` to `$hostesses = $hostesses->where('lastname', 'like', Input::get('l').'%');`

Comment: I doubt it, it looks like they're using a fluid interface which allows method chaining, and the OP said it worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738380/laravel-4-eloquent-models-chaining-additional-where-clauses/21739314#21739314

Comment: In that example, they are not calling the class statically, like in the OP's example. I'm not at all familiar with Eloquent, but in the post you linked to, that person was able to call ->where() without the assignment.

Comment: if we do this. 

{{ $results->links() }}

then url for next page will be. 

/?page=2

and get parameter from our request will be gone. and with that our where condition will be no more valid. 

what should i do then??