# Paginate an Eloquent query with join, where and orderBy-laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-4, eloquent

I have following ORM

```
$trucksobj = DB::Table('trucks')
             ->orderBy('trucks.id','desc')
             ->join('trucktypes', 'trucks.trucktype_id', '=', 'trucktypes.id');

if($overweight=="on") 
        $trucksobj->where('trucktypes.max_weight', '>', 'trucks.weight');

$trucks=$trucksobj->get();
```

It work like a charm, but when i replace `get()` with `paginate()` it is not responding  i.e

```
$trucks=$trucksobj->paginate(5);
```

is not working?

any thing i have missed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23393889/5984332 refer this.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this :http://culttt.com/2014/02/24/working-pagination-laravel-4/

Please us paginator function when you use manual query:

```
$trucksobj = DB::Table('trucks')
             ->orderBy('trucks.id','desc')
             ->join('trucktypes', 'trucks.trucktype_id', '=', 'trucktypes.id');

if($overweight=="on") 
        $trucksobj->where('trucktypes.max_weight', '>', 'trucks.weight');

$trucks=$trucksobj->get();

//$paginator = Paginator::make($items, $totalItems, $perPage);
$paginator = Paginator::make($trucks, count($trucks), 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function pagination()
 {
    $users = DB::table('img')
        ->join('category', 'category.id', '=', 'img.category_id')
        ->select('img.category_id', 'category.name', 'img.img_url')
        ->paginate(2);

    return view('page', compact('users'));
 }
```