# Laravel 5 eloquent conditional chaining query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Need help on this simple code, what code should I replace at 
`$users = User::all();` so I can conditional chaining the scope method and paginate it at the end?

I tried initiate the `User` object with `$users = new User();` and there is error, Trying to get property of non-object error when using at `VIEW`.

```
public function index()
{
    // user search

    $name = $this->request->name;
    $email = $this->request->email;

    $users = User::all();

    if (!empty($name)) {
        $users->name($name);
    }

    if (!empty($email)) {
        $users->email($email);
    }

    $users->paginate(5);

    return view('admin.users.index',compact('users'));
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you trying to display all users?

Comment: I want to filter user by name or email when admin hit search button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from the following link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21739314/417899

Eg code:

```
$users = new User;

if (!empty($name)) {
    $users = $users->name($name);
}

$users = $users ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: this really works, I was paginating, but was not assigning pagination result back to model instance.

Answer (score 2):

```
$users = DB::table('users');

$users = empty($email) ? $users->paginate(5) : $users->whereEmail($email)->paginate(5);
```

You do not need to check for a name if all users have an email, because email is always unique. That way to do the task is faster and more convinient.

In case, if you need to check `name` or anything else, you can use this:

```
$users = DB::table('users');

$users = empty($email) ? $users : $users->whereEmail($email);
$users = empty($name) ? $users : $users->whereName($name);

$users = $users->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Thanks will try later. I actually want to give option whether search by name or admin, or both. Actually the question is just example for more complex filter such as Property filter by type and square feet

Comment: I've updated my post, so you can add much more WHEREs to your query.

Comment: Hi I found the correct answer on the following link http://stackoverflow.com/a/21739314/417899

Comment: Well, your own answer doesn't answer your original question, also it doesn't answer second question which you asked in the first comment. At least you could upvote mine and cresjie's posts to thank us for our time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$users = new User;
if( !empty($name) )
   $users->whereName($name);
if( !empty($email) )
   $users->whereEmail($email);
$users =$users->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Thanks I will try later and let you know the result

Comment: Hi I found the correct answer on the following link http://stackoverflow.com/a/21739314/417899